# Is it possible to load CI models, libraries, and helpers outside CI application directory?

Tags: codeigniter

I am using a REST API outside CodeIgniter application directory and I want to be able to access CI models, libraries, and helpers so I don't have to copy-paste the same function on my REST API folder. I'm hoping not to repeat the functions.

Is there anyway I can do that? I'm using Restler API and I can't make it work within CI so I did it outside CI app folder.

Thanks!

Comment: use php include to include these files

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST library written by Philsturgeon and it would be very easy and you can access anything of the framework. I have used this library in my projects so I know it's very easy to configure and use by my experience.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually maintaining a codeigniter version that allows to create Rest calls (json) from models methods directly. Here's how I do it:

```
MODEL
function api_simplearray()
{
    return Array(1,2,4,5,6,7);
}

CONTROLLER
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('MyModel');
}
```

URL: /index.php/CONTROLLER/api_simplearray/

*Important: The model must be loaded in the constructor.